# Refresh main view after choosing calendar and hitting back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, refresh, back

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-event-kit-programming-tutorial/) from AppCoda and I noticed that when I create another calendar, choose it (indicated by the checkmark beside it), then hit the Back button, the events in the main UIViewController view are not refreshed. I already added this code in my `ViewController.m` but nothing new happened:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (self.tblEvents == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Your TableView becomes nil");
        return;
    }
    [self.tblEvents reloadData];
}
```

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more information.

Edit:

.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrEvents;

- (void)requestAccessToEvents;
- (void)loadEvents;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.tblEvents.delegate = self;
    self.tblEvents.dataSource = self;

    [self performSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEvents) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadEvents) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    [self.tblEvents reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tblEvents reloadData];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"idSegueEvent"]) {
        EventViewController *eventViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        eventViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate and Datasource method implementation

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.arrEvents.count);
    return self.arrEvents.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCellEvent"];

    // Get each single event.
    EKEvent *event = [self.arrEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Set its title to the cell's text label.
    cell.textLabel.text = event.title;

    // Get the event start date as a string value.
    NSString *startDateString = [self.appDelegate.eventManager getStringFromDate:event.startDate];

    // Get the event end date as a string value.
    NSString *endDateString = [self.appDelegate.eventManager getStringFromDate:event.endDate];

    // Add the start and end date strings to the detail text label.
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", startDateString, endDateString];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 60.0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Keep the identifier of the event that's about to be edited.
    self.appDelegate.eventManager.selectedEventIdentifier = [[self.arrEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] eventIdentifier];

    // Perform the segue.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idSegueEvent" sender:self];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the selected event.
        [self.appDelegate.eventManager deleteEventWithIdentifier:[[self.arrEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] eventIdentifier]];

        // Reload all events and the table view.
        [self loadEvents];
    }
}

#pragma mark - EEventViewControllerDelegate method implementation

- (void)eventWasSuccessfullySaved
{
    // Reload all events.
    [self loadEvents];
}

#pragma mark - IBAction method implementation

- (IBAction)showCalendars:(id)sender
{
    if (self.appDelegate.eventManager.eventsAccessGranted) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idSegueCalendars" sender:self];
    }
}

- (IBAction)createEvent:(id)sender
{
    if (self.appDelegate.eventManager.eventsAccessGranted) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idSegueEvent" sender:self];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Private method implementation

- (void)requestAccessToEvents
{
    [self.appDelegate.eventManager.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            // Store the returned granted value.
            self.appDelegate.eventManager.eventsAccessGranted = granted;
        } else {
            // In case of error, just log its description to the debugger.
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)loadEvents
{
    if (self.appDelegate.eventManager.eventsAccessGranted) {
        self.arrEvents = [self.appDelegate.eventManager getEventsOfSelectedCalendar];

        [self.tblEvents reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate of UITableView?

Comment: Hello @SyedeHussaini. I just started learning iOS programming. What do you mean by your question?

Comment: did you finish that tutorial ?

Comment: @Mahesh yes, I downloaded their full project.

Comment: then check that `numberOfRowsInSection` method returns > 0.

Comment: @Mahesh In here it returns `self.arrEvents.count;`

Comment: @ClarkeGray yes exactly. But my question is that is array contains any object ? print the array count right before that line and it should not be zero.

Comment: @Mahesh I printed it and it's not 0. Each of the calendars I made in this app has 1 event (with different names)

Answer (score 0):

To make UITableView work you need to set the delegate and datasource object like this..

in you ViewController.m file try to add Delegate and DataSource like this.

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

now add these two lines in your view did load.

```
self.tblEvents.delegate = self;
self.tblEvents.dataSource = self;
```

And check the implimentation of you Data Source methods like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    //This method should return the number of rows you want to create in your tableView
    return yourArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourCellIdentifier"];
//Now show what you want to show in your each cell? For Example you just want to show a simple text which is stored in you array.
cell.textLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//indexPath.row is the numeric index number of each cell. This method will automatically execute exact the same number of time you return in above method.
return cell;
}
```

Now When your `class/View Controller` is open you might have zero data in your array and after some manipulation you  got some data in your array Either by Call Web-Services/Loading from local Database/ by Passing Reference of array to next `ViewController` and on coming back to screen you want to refresh your `TableView` so now calling `[tblEvents reloadData]` will restart the process from `numberOfRowsInSection` method to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't really manipulate the code in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from the downloaded project. Also, I created one event on each of my created calendars. When I create a new event (by clicking the + button) then hit Save, screen will redirect to main view then that's the only time the main view is refreshed according to the currently selected calendar.

Comment: Can you share your main ViewControllers code so that i can find and resolve the issue

Comment: Have you add this <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> in your MainViewController.h file?

Comment: Added a line in your viewWillAppear method to check wether your tableView becomes nil or anything else.

Comment: Hello. I am still encountering the problem. Searched the web but still the same.

Comment: Have you check that your tableView object is not became nil when comes back to this screen?